# Obtaining all pairwise scatterplots amongst variables

Tags: r

Im trying to solve this question with the dataframe stackloss:

```
Use the pairs() function to obtain all pairwise scatterplots among the 
four variables.
```

However when i use the pairs function I get a graph with all the variables plotted together. How can i make sure that i only get the variables pairwise so only two variables will appear per graph window?
My code is:

```
pairs(stackloss,pch=21,bg=c("red","green","yellow","blue"))
```

Thank you

Comment: `pairs()` is the wrong function for that. Try `plot()` within for loops.

Comment: You could also use ggplot2 with facet_wrap() on e.g. row number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not quite clear how you want to obtain all plots. I put the `plot()` function in two loops and use the `Sys.sleep()` function to have a small break between every call of the command. If you use R-studio you can switch between the last shown plots.

```
for(ii in 1:(ncol(stackloss)-1) ){
  begin <- ii + 1
  for(i in begin:ncol(stackloss)){
    plot(x=stackloss[,ii], y=stackloss[,i], xlab=colnames(stackloss)[ii], ylab=colnames(stackloss)[i])
    Sys.sleep(1)
  }
}
```